# How to display data from Vuex store in life time in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I want o show data from Vues store. So first I want to check if authentication true, if it is, I want to show data from Vuex. Here is my shortcode:

```
<li v-if="authenticated">
                            Hello, {{ getUser.attributes.first_name }}
                        </li>


computed: {
    getUser() {
        console.log(this.$store.state.user)
        return this.$store.state.user;
    }
},
```

But I am getting error like you see in the picture below, why do you think it might be? Why first the object is coming empty and then object is filled?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to the `v-if` directive because at the first rendering the `attributes` property is not available :

```html
<li v-if="authenticated && getUser.attributes">
    Hello, {{ getUser.attributes.first_name }}
</li>
```